# Having trouble logging in users using Passport.js, express-session and Youtube oauth

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, youtube-data-api, express-session

To capture the issue - I am using youtube's data API OAuth for authenticating users and authorizing my app. to keep track of users and their tokens I set up a mongo dB to store sessions as well as app data (users metadata and tokens included). the problem I have is that once a user had authenticated the app, I can see the session data properly stored in the session store, including user id, but when I make consecutive calls to my backend - the user is not logged in.

I'll describe the flow of what I did and then add some code snippets to make it a bit more clear (hopefully):

The client initiates the OAuth flow by redirecting to the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube with all required parameters. once the user had authorized the app - the redirection URI (specified in google API dashboard) redirect the result to my backend.
on my backend, I use express-session and passport js with the passport-youtube-v3 strategy. as mentioned, the login/signup part seems to be working fine. I can see the a new user is registered in my users' collection and the session stored includes that user id. I can also see the session is stored in a cookie on the client. To the best of my understanding - once a consecutive API call had been initiated - the session cookie should be included in the request and passport should authenticate the user. however, when I guard any endpoint with passport.authenticate('youtube') or a simple req.isAuthenticted() check - the request stops there and the next middleware or function is not invoked (meaning the user is not logged in I assume). if I remove these guards (for the sake of debugging) what I am getting on the request object seems like a whole new session altogether. it has a different expiry timestamp, missing user data (or the cookie property).

here is a bit of code to illustrate what I am doing, I am surely doing something wrong - I just can't figure out what...

server.js

```
const mongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const sessionStore = new mongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  collection: "sessions",
});
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// set up routes ...
```

passport.js

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  console.log("deserializeUser", id);
  userModel
    .findById(id)
    .then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
});

passport.use(
  new YoutubeV3Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/youtube/redirect",
      scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"],
      authorizationParams: {
        access_type: "offline",
      },
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // console.log("passport verify cb", profile);
      let user = await getUser(profile.id);
      // console.log("user", user);
      if (!user) {
        user = await addUser({
          youtubeId: profile.id,
          name: profile.displayName,
          accessToken: accessToken,
          refreshToken: refreshToken,
        });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

an example for a route called after user authorized the app and is registered in db (both in user collection and a session created in session store):

```
router.get("/someendpoint", (req, res) => {
  console.log("isAuthenticated", req.isAuthenticated()); // false
  console.log("session", req.session); // a session object that does not correspond to anything in my session store. 
});
```

As mentioned, if I guard this endpoint with passport.authenticate('youtube') or a simple req.isAuthenticated() check the code doesn't get anywhere past that guard.

some additional info that helps you help me:

1. my client and server run on localhost but on different ports
2. the 'some endpoint' endpoint is on a different path than the endpoints I use for managing the OAuth flow.

Your help is much appreciated...